# Jboss LdapExtLoginModule and Active Directory

Tags: java, jsp, jboss, active-directory, ldap

Hi I was wondering if anyone had come across any guides or had any knowledge on how to validate login using JBoss 4.2.3's LdapExtLoginModule from an networked Active Directory. I have been searching online for quite awhile but have only come across people asking for help on certain cases without any explanation of how they implemented their system. I will also be querying to check if the given user is part of a specific group so any info regarding this using LdapExtLoginModule would also be very helpful.

Thanks :)